# JSON schema validation returns Unexpected token encountered when reading value for 'required'. Expected StartObject, got StartArray

Tags: json, syntax-error, schema

I've generated the following schema, but once I try to validate (on `jsonschemavalidator.net`) I get an error:
`Unexpected token encountered when reading value for 'required'. Expected StartObject, got StartArray.`

The JSON schema is:

```
  {
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "rioolwaterzuivering": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "zandvanger": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "kogelafsluiter": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "tagcode": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "materiaal": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "diameter": {
                  "type": "number"
                },
                "required": [
                  "tagcode",
                  "materiaal",
                  "diameter"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What causes this problem?

Comment: That's not a python problem. You'd better go for the .net's document https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/Introduction.htm

Answer (score -1):

The issue has already been resolved. The required properties clause was nested too much. It had to be on level higher.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer doesn't contribute any way of solution. Please add some more information that could help people in the future.